# Visual Studio Paths Missing Slash

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm between a rock and a hard place it seems. After updating my Visual Studio 2013, I was unable to load my C# projects. I looked at the activity log and found the error code is 80070002 (which relates to a missing file) and the file path was missing a slash (`H:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0Common7\IDE\...`). I found out that running `devenv /Setup` seemed to fix the problem, but now the path keeps going back to missing the slash.

I couldn't get the error related to unable to load the C# project because I saved the wrong activity log before repairing Visual Studio. But I got this error which is the same:

```
  <entry>
    <record>955</record>
    <time>2014/08/19 03:56:21.646</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>CreateInstance failed for package [SqlStudio Profile Package]</description>
    <guid>{00A9524F-427F-46EE-8A20-615C25ECBE6F}</guid>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'file:///H:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.SqlProfile.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

Anybody know what might be causing this issue and/or if there's anything to change so it includes the slash in the path?

Comment: Try search the registry or the extensions folder for file content.

Comment: @leppie The problem with that is there's too many registry and files to change. It would help if I knew what was changing them back.

Comment: OK... The problems seems quite a bigger than I thought :) Re-install Windows? :D